# Convert string to UTF-8 with terminal only

Tags: encoding, utf-8

How I can convert a string to UTF-8 encoding using Ubuntu terminal only?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! From what encoding are you trying to convert?

Answer (score 6):

`iconv` should do what you are looking for

eg.:

```
echo 'latin string' | iconv -t utf-8 > yourfileInUTF8
```

Edit: 
As suggested by damadam I removed the `-f` option since the string typed in terminal uses the default encoding

> -f, --from-code=NAME       encoding of original text

Comment: Thank you but I found many examples on file, not for some string that's why I opened this question

Comment: ah ok updated, you can try but I honestly don't know if a simple string can contain the encoding information

Comment: you can remove the `-f` option if OP wants to type the string from terminal, it takes the default encoding; also, I think it's better to use double quote `"` for the `echo` command

Comment: @damadam Whether `'` or `"` should be used depends on the particular case. `'` doesn’t allow any expansion and is perfectly valid here.

Comment: @damadam: Thank you for your feedback | Melebius: Ok I understand